# joSQL query with double quotes parsing resulting org.josql.parser.TokenMgrError: Lexical error

Tags: parsing, double-quotes, lexical, josql

Trying to run following code, in this the SQL statement trying to find values where colName2 like group/test" (name having double quote in the end), and passing the querySQL string to josql parser.

```
public static void main(String a[])
{
    String querySQL = new String("Select * from tabName WHERE ((colName1) = ((\"type\" )) AND (colName2) LIKE ((\"%group/test\"%\" ))) ORDER BY colName2 asc");
    org.josql.Query josql = new org.josql.Query();
    try
    {
        josql.parse(querySQL);
    } 
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println(josql.toString());
}
```

Following exception has been occurring when I run it, as colName2 contains a string with double quote in it. Does anyone has any idea on how to pass the double quote to josql parser?

Exception in thread "main" org.josql.parser.TokenMgrError: Lexical error at line 1, column 150.  Encountered:  after : "\" ))) ORDER BY colName2 asc"
at org.josql.parser.JoSQLParserTokenManager.getNextToken(JoSQLParserTokenManager.java:1420)
at org.josql.parser.JoSQLParser.jj_scan_token(JoSQLParser.java:3725)
.........
.........

at org.josql.parser.JoSQLParser.Query(JoSQLParser.java:298) 
at org.josql.parser.JoSQLParser.parseQuery(JoSQLParser.java:86)
at org.josql.Query.parse(Query.java:2032)
at main.JoSqlTest.main(JoSqlTest.java:12)

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need double quotes?

You can/should use single quotes here...

"Select * from tabName WHERE colName1 = 'type' AND colName2 LIKE '%group/test\"%' ORDER BY colName2 asc"